# How to install JAVA 8 Debian 8

Tags: java, linux, debian

I´ve been installing java 8 in debian jessie in this following away below:

```
echo "deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu trusty main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/webupd8team-java.list

echo "deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu trusty main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/webupd8team-java.list

apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys EEA14886
apt-get update && apt-get install oracle-java8-installer -y
```

but sunddenly , this isn't  working anymore.

```
E: Unable to find the oracle8-java-installer package
```

i tried this another step below, but i getting the same error:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

Comment: The ppa(s) have shut down due to Oracle's licensing changes. You need to download the Oracle JDK from Oracle; or switch to OpenJDK.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Download (oracle account needed) from

https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

jdk-8u211-linux-x64.tar.gz

As root

```
cp jdk-8u211-linux-x64.tar.gz /usr/lib/jvm/

cd /usr/lib/jvm/

tar zxvf jdk-8u211-linux-x64.tar.gz
```

To set as default run:

```
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_211/bin/java 4

update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/javac javac /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_211/bin/javac 4

update-alternatives --config java
```

[image]

Then choose option **4**
(because previously run update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_211/bin/java **4**)

Source:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/install/linux_jdk.html#BJFJJEFG